How to solve $f(x)=f(0)+\frac{x}{f'(x_{0})+\frac{x^{2}}{f''(x_{0})+\ddots}}$ for $f(x)$?
Question
How to solve
\begin{align*}
f\left( x \right) &= f_{0} + \underset{k = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}\left[ \frac{x^{k}}{f^{\left( k \right)}\left( x_{0} \right)} \right] = f_{0} + \frac{x}{f'\left( x_{0} \right) + \frac{x^{2}}{f''\left( x_{0} \right) + \frac{x^{3}}{f'''\left( x_{0} \right) + \ddots}}}\\
\end{align*}
for $f\left( x \right)$ where $\operatorname{K}$ denotes a continued fraction where $f_{0}$ and $x_{0}$ are some constants? I'm not necessarily looking for a closed-form solution (if one exists). Series solutions, numerical solutions, ..., solution methods/ideas, ... I'm interested in all of that too (including special cases).
I just wanted the solution to be as general as possible (e.g. $f{:}\, \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$).
Motivation:
I was playing around with Mathematica's $\operatorname{ContinuedFractionK}\left[ f,\, g,\, \left\{ i,\, i_{\text{min}},\, i_{\text{max}} \right\} \right]$ and noticed that a surprising number of functions seemed to have the term $\underset{k = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}\left[ \frac{x^{k}}{f^{\left( k \right)}\left( x_{0} \right)} \right]$ converging and that's when the question came up. The problem: I can't find a single function satisfying the relation.
My work
It's easy to see that if $x = 0$ then $\fbox{$f_{0} = f\left( 0 \right)$}$. It also follows that $f\left( \varepsilon \right) = f\left( 0 \right) + \frac{\varepsilon}{f'\left( x_{0} \right)}$ where $\varepsilon \ne 0 = \varepsilon^{2}$, so if $f$ is analytic around $x = 0$, then $f\left( 0 \right) + \frac{\varepsilon}{f'\left( x_{0} \right)} = f\left( 0 \right) + f'\left( 0 \right) \cdot \varepsilon$ aka $\fbox{$f'\left( x_{0} \right) = \frac{1}{f'\left( 0 \right)}$}$, or more general: if $f$ is analytic around $x = a$, then $f\left( a \right) + \frac{b \cdot \varepsilon}{f'\left( x_{0} \right)} = f\left( a \right) + b \cdot f'\left( a \right) \cdot \varepsilon$ aka $\fbox{$f'\left( x_{0} \right) = \frac{1}{f'\left( a \right)}$} 
 \wedge b \ne 0$. Problem: $f'\left( x_{0} \right) = \frac{1}{f'\left( a \right)}$ seems strange to me (so maybe there is no solution or $f$ is not analytic (?)).
$\underset{k = 1}{\overset{n}{\operatorname{K}}}\left[ \frac{x^{k}}{f^{\left( k \right)}\left( x_{0} \right)} \right]$ is only defined if $f^{\left( n \right)}\left( x_{0} \right) \ne 0$, so if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left[ \underset{k = 1}{\overset{n}{\operatorname{K}}}\left[ \frac{x^{k}}{f^{\left( k \right)}\left( x_{0} \right)} \right] \right] = \underset{k = 1}{\overset{\infty}{\operatorname{K}}}\left[ \frac{x^{k}}{f^{\left( k \right)}\left( x_{0} \right)} \right]$, then $\fbox{$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left[ f^{\left( n \right)}\left( x_{0} \right) \right] \ne 0$}$.
I can't get closer to an answer. I also tried special cases like constants, polynomials (which obviously did not work), trigonometric functions, exponential functions, ... I also tried an approximations via letting $f\left( x \right) \approx \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left[ \frac{f^{\left( k \right)}\left( 0 \right)}{k!} \cdot x^{k} \right]$.

I'm not sure I understand how you got the condition $f^{\left( n \right)}\left( x_{0} \right) \ne 0$. What about $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ with $n=1$ and $x_0=0$? Yes, there's a point discontinuity, but that doesn't affect the limit.

Would it be possible to use Euler’s continued fraction formula in reverse?

@kc9jud That's because $K_{k=1}^n[\frac{x^k}{f^{(k)}(x_0)}]$ implies that the last term in the continued fraction is $\frac{x^n}{f^{(n)}(x_0)}$, so if $f^{(n)}(x_0)=0$ then we have $\frac{x^n}{0}$ which is not defined, so $f^{(n)}(x_0)\ne0$. I'm not saying that all derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$ can't be zero (only the last term can't be $0$). Or am I wrong there?

Oh, I see, I think I misunderstood your limit. I guess I was thinking about removing that singularity -- you could instead look at $\lim_{z->x_0} K_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{x^k}{f^{(k)}(z)}\right]$, which would remove that singularity in some cases; crudely speaking, you'll have something that looks like $1/(1+1/0)$ which is "like" zero.

Also I just realized that my example with $\sqrt{x}$ is nonsense, ignore that...

In addition, note that the choice $x_0 = 0$ implies $f'(0) = \pm1$.

If $x_0=0$, then I think $f''(0)=0$ and higher order derivatives wouldn't exist at $0$. For other $x_0$, maybe you could show $f$ can't be complex analytic by showing certain bounds don't hold?

(Several remarks, too long for a comment)
I have tried to solve your problem for a while now, but unsuccessfully unforturnately. Nonetheless, here are a few remarks, which might help you to restate the problem and perhaps go further.
Unsurprisingly, the main difficulty lies in the generalized continued fraction on the right-hand side, which would require a closed form expression in $x$ and $f(x)$ ideally, in order to be compared to the left-hand side. Since continued fractions are somewhat hard to manipulate algebraically, we might "translate" them into other formalisms in order to take advantage of the associated tools.
Recurrence relations.
Basically, continued fractions are multi-levelled fractions, which can can be rewritten as a single fraction by finding the successive common denominators, so that the (finite) continued fraction
$$
C_n = \mathop{\rm K}_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{b_k} = \frac{A_n}{B_n}
$$
is described equivalenty by the following pair of recurrence relations :
$$
\begin{cases}
   A_n = b_nA_{n-1} + a_nA_{n-2} \\
   B_n = b_nB_{n-1} + a_nB_{n-2} 
\end{cases},
$$
together with the initial conditions :
$$
\begin{cases}
   A_{-1} = 1 \\
   B_{-1} = 0
\end{cases}
\quad\&\quad
\begin{cases}
   A_0 = b_0 \\
   B_0 = 1
\end{cases}
$$
Your problem is parametrized with $a_n = x^n$ and $b_n = f^{(n)}(x_0)$. However, second-order linear recurrence relations with variable coefficients are hard to solve in general, but now you may solve this problem as such. Personally, I tried to determine the associated generating function, but I doubt it is possible to disentangle the function $f(x)$ and the said generating function inside the term involving $b_n$ without any further assumptions about $f(x)$.
Möbius transformations.
Alternatively, continued fractions can be seen as compositions of linear fractional transformations of the Möbius group. More concretely, one has $C_n = \Phi_n(z=0)$, where $\Phi_n = \phi_0 \circ \ldots \circ \phi_n$, with $\phi_k(z) = \frac{a_k}{b_k+z}$ in the present case. The Möbius group is isomorphic to $PSL(2,\Bbb{C})$; in consequence, a general linear fractional transformation, i.e. $\phi(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ can be identified to the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$, acting on the equivalent class of collinear vectors $[z]$ as follows :
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \cdot [z] \equiv \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} z \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} az+b \\ cz+d \end{pmatrix} \equiv \left[\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right]
$$
In addition, the Möbius group is a Lie group, so that you can also rewrite a transformation $\phi(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ as $\phi = \exp\left((-cz^2+(a-d)z+b)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)$. I didn't succeed in work out your problem on this track, but now you can exploit tools from linear algebra, complex analysis or Lie algebras at the very least.
Hyperdual numbers.
Working at $x_0 = 0$ (in order to avoid two concurrent expansions at the origin and $x_0$), you might derive the coefficients $f^{(n)}(0)$ iteratively, in the same spirit as you did with dual numbers, with the help of hyperdual numbers. Those are of two kinds. You can consider either an imaginary unit with higher-order nilpotency, such as $\eta \neq 0$ with $\eta^2 \neq 0$ but $\eta^3 = 0$, hence
$$
f(\eta) = f(0) + f'(0)\eta + \frac{1}{2}f''(0)\eta^2 = f_0 + \frac{\eta}{f'(0) + \frac{\eta^2}{f''(0)}} = f_0 + \frac{\eta}{f'(0)},
$$
where we used the geometric series for the last equality. Alternatively, you can consider two commuting nilsquare imaginary units $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2 \neq 0$, i.e. with $\varepsilon_1^2 = \varepsilon_2^2 = 0$ and $\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon_2\varepsilon_1$, hence
$$
f(\varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2 + \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2) = f(0) + f'(0)(\varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2 + \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2) + f''(0)\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2
$$
on one side and
$$
f_0 + \frac{\varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2 + \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2}{f'(0) + \frac{2\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2}{f''(0)}} = f_0 + \frac{\varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2 + \varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2}{f'(0)}
$$
on the other side. Both methods lead to $f''(0) = 0$ at the end. However, the next coefficients $f^{(n)}(0)$ seem to involve more subtle relations.
